# Can't execute JavaScript cross origin, cross frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm working on a project that requires the use of an iframe on the **main website** (forced on https://www.domain.com), which loads a page with a form on a **sub domain** (https://my.domain.com). When the form is sent on mobile the **main website** stays on the position it was when the form was sent, while we want it to scroll to the top of the page. To do this, we want to use the following javascript from the **iframe** (subdomain):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(this).scrollTop(0);
  if(typeof window.parent != 'undefined')
  {
    window.parent.scroll(0,0);
  }
}
```

Doing this however leads to the following error in the console

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://my.domain.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
  at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (https://my.domain.com/files/js/aanmelden.js:160:16)
  at i (https://my.domain.com/files/js/vendor/jquery-1.12.0.min.js:2:27451)
  at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (https://my.domain.com/files/js/vendor/jquery-1.12.0.min.js:2:28215)
  at Function.ready (https://my.domain.com/files/js/vendor/jquery-1.12.0.min.js:2:30008)
  at HTMLDocument.K (https://my.domain.com/files/js/vendor/jquery-1.12.0.min.js:2:30370
```

We have tried to set a `document.domain` on the subdomain to **www.domain.com** and **domain.com**, but this did not solve the issue.

What can we do to solve this issue?

Comment: You're being blocked by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). See the question I marked as duplicate for more information and workarounds